# Create line breaks in output based on array index

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display output like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 1 2
```

I've tried this code:

```
$num = ['1','2','3','4','....'];
$size = sizeof($num) / 4;
foreach ($num as $key => $value) {
  echo $value;
  if($key >= round($size){
    echo "<br>"
  }
}
```

But the output is like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5
6
7
8
...
```

Can anyone suggest how to write the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$num= ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
$size = sizeof($num) / 4;
foreach ($num as $key => $value){
   echo $value;
   if(($key+1) % 4 == 0){
      echo "<br>";
    }
   }
```

You can use modulus instead of round. Cool I didn't know about sizeOf! Good to know. Mark this as the right answer pwease if this works!

Another way to do this if you didn't want to write out all the numbers that are in the Num Array is to just push them into an array with a while loop.

```
$num= [];
$i = 1;

//Set the Num Variable to have as many numbers as you want without having to manually enter them in
while ($i < 100) {
     array_push($num, $i);
     $i++;
}

//Run the actual code that adds breaks ever 4 lines
$size = sizeof($num) / 4;
foreach ($num as $key => $value){
   echo $value;
   if(($key+1) % 4 == 0){
      echo "<br>";
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this answer looks the same as the first answer but I will explain it clearer

To achieve what you want

Step 1: Create a for loop

The loop will start from 1 to it's total size of the array

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= sizeof($num); $x++){

}
```

Then inside your loop

you can use ternary for simplicity

This line of code

```
# if $x variable is equal to limit number which you wanted to break
# $num[$x-1] -> subtract to by 1 because we know array always start at index 0

if ($x % 4 == 0) {
    $num[$x-1]."<br>"; #put a break after it
} else {
    echo $num[$x-1];
}
```

is same as this

```
echo ($x % 4 == 0) ? $num[$x-1]."<br>" : $num[$x-1];
```

So try this

```
<?php

$num= ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'];
$size = sizeof($num) / 4;
for ($x = 1; $x <= sizeof($num); $x++){
   echo ($x % 4 == 0) ? $num[$x-1]."<br>" : $num[$x-1];
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/763941)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 8, 19, 20];

$len = 1;

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
  echo $number . ' ';
  $len++;
  if ($len > 4) {
    echo '<br>';
    $len = 1;
  }     
}
```